# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript

i have something like this, but i dont get where is the problem. Console says - `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

```
<div class="price-table-box"></div>
<div class="price-table-box"></div>
<div class="price-table-box"></div>
<div class="price-table-box"></div>

var table = document.getElementsByClassName('price-table-box');

for (var i = 0; i <= table.length; i++) {
    table[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looping through too many elements.  `table[4]` doesn't exist, so it's `undefined`.

Loop from 0-3, not from 0-4:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot that in programming everything starts with 0.

Answer (score -1):

It's been pointed out that you're trying to access an element of the array that doesn't exist. Additionally keep in mind that you can't access DOM objects through 'document.get...' methods until after the page has finished loading because they don't yet exist technically, or aren't yet accessible. You need to put your javascript into a window.onload event handler or similar.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('price-table-box');

    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        table[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

make sure to put everything you need for onload into this function (or call it from it) or you'll overwrite your previous declaration(s).